# Python: Why my Process stay alive on TK VS killed on command line (windows)

Tags: python, process, terminate

On TK I do that:
[image]

sys.exit(1) will exit the tk and the other threads running.
But all Processes triggered will stay alive in memory (I still see the logs file fill up).

To be more accurate:

**python Main.py** trigger process **python schdule.py** that trigger process **python start.py**
I see logs in start.py

On the other hand not using TK, and killing the command line with X button

Leave no process alive - not accurate, they will keep on running until die with exception in a print
statement / some OS error things... WHY ?

[image]